# In JOOQ, when should I use Configuration.dsl() versus DSL.using(Configuration)?

Tags: jooq

In JOOQ, when should I use `Configuration.dsl()` versus `DSL.using(Configuration)`? Both methods take a `Configuration` and return a `DSLContext` but it isn't clear from the documentation (or the implementation) if there's any practical difference. Are they the same? If not, how does one determine when to use one or the other?

For example, say I'm writing the `run` of a `TransactionalRunnable`,  which is passed a `Configuration`. I need a `DSLContext` in order to perform some queries in the transaction. What is the correct method to use to obtain a `DSLContext` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `DefaultConfiguration`, they are the same. [`Configuration.dsl()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Configuration.html#dsl()) is just convenience for [`DSL.using(Configuration)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using(org.jooq.Configuration)). If you implemented your own `Configuration`, you could override this behaviour.

Granted, this could be mentioned in the Javadoc: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9289